# How to save cost when using Amazon instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Let's say I have a linux instance in Amazon and I save everything in the EBS. I only need to use the instance a few times in a month therefore, normally I will "stop" the instance and "start" it when I need to use it.  Beside this, I wonder if there is any further way to save more cost? The EBS is allocated all the time - can that be moved into s3 and put back to EBS when I need to use the instance?

By default, the EBS comes with 8Gb of stores. It was created by the image instance. Let say we already put data in the EBS. Can the EBS trim the size smaller from 8gb to 1gb, so I save cost?

Comment: Use 'spot' instances and set your maximum price at the standard price of that instance. 99% of the time the cost of an instance will be less than the full price of a standard instance, but the maximum price will be the standard price so at worst you just pay the standard price.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest cost for EC2 is usually going to be CPU, unless you're building a huge site for delivery of images, video etc. I have written some advice recently as to how you can reduce your EC2 costs: http://blog.labslice.com/2011/01/3-ways-to-reduce-your-amazon-ec2-cloud.html. If you usage is really infrequent, then of-course you should just stop and restart machines on a need-be basis. Being smart about that can easily cut your bills by a large percentage. And if you want some automation to help machine costs then you may want to look at our product at http://LabSlice.com, as it's specifically built to manage costs for EC2.